# Add label to an existing Jira Issue using the Java Jira Client

Tags: java, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to update a Jira Issue and add/update some field.

I am using https://www.baeldung.com/jira-rest-api to setup my java rest client. I can now connect and update some of the fields for the Jira Issue.

I am unable to find how to add labels to existing issue which has labels. In the current code the label is getting replaced. The current issue has say labels 'A' and 'B', I want to add label NEW_LABEL.

```
    private void updateIssue(String issueKey) {
        //update parent, version
        IssueInput input = new IssueInputBuilder()
                .setFieldValue(PARENT_LINK_FEATURE,PARENT_LINK_FEATURE_VALUE)
                .setFixVersions(Collections.singletonList(createVerion()))
               .setFieldValue(IssueFieldId.LABELS_FIELD.id,
                        Collections.singletonList("NEW_LABEL"))
                        
                .build();
        JiraRestClient restClient = JiraUtils.createRestClient();
        restClient.getIssueClient()
                .updateIssue(issueKey, input)
                .claim();
    }
```

I would like some support to add a label to an existing Issue, without having to retrieve and add the labels again.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any resolution using the Java API.

I did solve the issue using the Rest API. Generic code for invoking the rest URI.

```
public static void updateIssue(JsonObject issueObject,String ISSUE_KEY) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(issueObject);

        LOGGER.debug("JSON : {}", json);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String uri = SecureUtils.getBaseURL() + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + ISSUE_KEY;
        LOGGER.debug("URL : {}", uri);
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(uri);
        httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPut.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + getEncodedCredentials());
        // Set JSON payload as the request entity
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(issueObject.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpPut.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);

        // Check the response status code
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
            LOGGER.info("Label and fix version updated successfully.");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to update label and fix version. Status code: " + statusCode);
        }

        // Consume and close the response
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

I created a JsonObject for the below payload. The sample adds 3 labels and also some custom fields.

```
    {
  "update": {
    "labels": [
      {
        "add": "Label1"
      },
      {
        "add": "Label3"
      },
      {
        "add": "Label5"
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "customfield_15502": "Field1",
    "customfield_15504": "2023-10-01"
  }
}
```

Reference API used: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.22.4/#issue-editIssue